# Using drawText with an array

Tags: java, android

I was wondering is it possible to use drawText with an array so that it doesn't place each word onto of the other?

```
 for(int count =0; count<2; count++)
    {
        canvas.drawText(words[count], x, y, paint);

    }//for
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `x` or `y`, so:

```
for (int count = 0; count < words.length; count++) {
  canvas.drawText(words[count], x + 10 * count, y, paint);
}
```

Here, word[0] would be drawn at (x, y) and word[1] would be drawn at (x + 10, y). This isn't very robust, however; it assumes that all words are 10 px wide.

Comment: Great for basic concept and explanation. Depending on the length of each word in the array `x` or `y` values can be incremented.

Comment: There's also a `measureText(String)` method on `Paint` that should help, e.g. `x += paint.measureText(words[count]);`